# Saturdays' Sequences

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence, letter-sequence

1. **0.469281  0.267974  0.333333  0.333333  0.666667  0.499346  0.333333**
2. **2 2 1 1 2 2 1**
3. **3 2 F 0 0 0 0**
4. **U P F O X F E**
5. **0 0 1 1 2 1 1**

Here are 5 intertwined sequences. I will add one sequence each saturday until this puzzle is solved. Saturday added sequence will be connected to all previous sequences.

This puzzle is to explain why all those sequences are inter-connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The common thread is

> colours of the rainbow, from short-wavelength to long-wavelength, represented as RGB triples.

```
0.469281 0.267974 0.333333 0.333333 0.666667 0.499346 0.333333
```

> Average of RGB components, divided by 255.

```
2 2 1 1 2 2 1
```

> Number of nonzero components.

```
3 2 F 0 0 0 0
```

> Last hex digit in #rrggbb representation.

```
U P F O X F E
```

> Last letter of colour name, shifted by one.

```
0 0 1 1 2 1 1
```

> Number of 0xFF components.

However,

> I can't find any standard "violet" that actually quite fits all these. Some sources say it's #4f2f4f which has the right sum but doesn't match your other sequences. Some sources say it's #7f00ff which matches two of your sequences but has the wrong sum and last hex digit.

Comment: Your "however" makes it clear that the rest of this answer is entirely coincidence. ;)

Comment: That would be quite a coincidence. :-)

Comment: Well, turns out it's not a coïncidence! There are infinite RGB representations of rainbow's colors. I used this one: https://www.webnots.com/vibgyor-rainbow-color-codes/ You can adapt your correct asnwer based on this representation if you want. Congrats to you ;)

Comment: I didn't except the community to solve it under a week haha, I thought I'd add at least one sequence